# Combine two update statements together in kdb+

Tags: sql-update, kdb

I tried to combine two update statements together. It is because if I don't update together, the first update statement will affect the second update statement but I am not sure how.

```
tab:update trade:`$ssr[;"-01";""]each string deal from tab where  ((-1#'string trade) like enlist "0") and (-3#'string deal) like "-01"
tab:update trade:`$ssr[;"-01";"SP"]each string deal from tab where  ((-1#'string trade) like enlist "1") and (-3#'string deal) like "-01";
```

If I do not combine, my first statement may have 1 to trade and later one second update statement will add SP because there is 1.

Answer (score 0):

```
t:([] trade:`trade0`trade0`trade1`trade1`trade2; deal:`1_00`2_01`3_00`4_01`5_01)

update newtrade:`$ {$[y>1;x;ssr[x;"_01";("";"_SP")@y]]} ./: flip(string deal;"01"?last each string trade) from t where deal like "*_01"


trade  deal newtrade
--------------------
trade0 1_00         
trade0 2_01 2       
trade1 3_00         
trade1 4_01 4_SP    
trade2 5_01 5_01
```

Comment: I think last row output is not as per the requirement.

Comment: @Rahul: yes you're right. I've edited the answer but of course it is now almost the same as yours

Answer (score 0):

Taking example help from Alexander:

```
  q) t:([] trade:`trade0`trade0`trade1`trade1`trade2; deal:`$("1-00";"20-01";"3-00";"4-01";"5-01"))
```

Solution:

- check if trade matches with element of the list (*0;*1).
- get the index of matched element.
- 2 means no match which means return original trade value
- Else use ssr to replace the string with proper value -> ("";"SP")@a .

  ```
  q) t2: update trade:{$[2>a:(x like/: ("*0";"*1"))?1b;`$ssr[y;"-01";("";"SP")@a];x]}'[trade;string deal] from t where deal like "*-01"
  ```

Original:

```
 q) t:update trade:`$ssr[;"-01";""]each string deal from t where  ((-1#'string trade) like enlist "0") and (-3#'string deal) like "-01"
 q) t:update trade:`$ssr[;"-01";"SP"]each string deal from t where  ((-1#'string trade) like enlist "1") and (-3#'string deal) like "-01";

 q) t~ t2 / true
```